# Inherited an ASP.NET website application with 60,000 url redirects

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

Not Joking.. Using the IIS plugin UrlRewrite, we're sporting a map config that is pushing 8mb. It contains 60,000 entries of "from -> to" rules. The config is so large, we have to adjust the registry to accommodate the size of the config file.

The redirects mainly consist of:

> 1. .html -> .aspx during a migration to asp.net
> 2. pages that have been renamed
> 3. short lived campaigns redirecting back to the home page
> 4. and all the redirects are replicated 18 times, one for each language folder such as /us/*, /uk/*, etc.

We are gearing up to significantly reduce the amount of redirects, so this is not my concern. My concern is around the 3-4 new redirect requests every week or so. Manually adding redirect entries to the config file and propagating to production servers is getting tedious and time consuming.

What is being discussed is, considering the 60,000 redirects as "legacy redirects" and will be reduced on a separate thread. For all future redirects, content editors will create files that match the "From" url pattern that contain Response.Redirects to the "To" address.

I am appalled with this approach because what we're going to have is a ton of redirects with UrlRewrite and a growing number of one-liner redirect files scattered through out the website. I predict an epic disaster. The worst part about it is I can't think of a better solution.

My question to you all is, what is the best practices for managing redirects of a large and changing website like this? Is there a .net technology that is well suited for exactly this dilemma?

Comment: Have you considered putting a URL mapping service in front of your ASP.NET website? The URL mapping service can store the rules in its own data store, keep them in a cache for quickly generating the mapped URL given a URL and redirect the user to the mapped URL on the ASP.NET site. You can release the URL mapping service independent of the ASP.NET site achieving separation of responsibilities.

Comment: Are these established as 301 (permanent) redirects? If so, are you seeing much traffic on the oldest ones? If not, they may be safe to delete. :)

Comment: Have you considered using a database to store these redirect rules (and build a front end to manage them). Then you would only need a few core redirects which never change but handle any URLs passed into it. I would probably need a few examples of redirects to recommend an actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would forgo the massive redirects all together. Talk about a nightmare. Just serve up the pages you intend to at the correct paths.

If you get a request for a page that doesn't exist, instead of showing the 404 Not Found, have the webserver handle the request by performing a lookup into a datastore for a matching "new destination" (this could be done with a special ASP page). Your datastore would contain the old-to-new mappings, and if one match exist, the user will get redirected. If not, then show the true 404 (and a kind message to the user to update their links).

This gets you out of the business of writing massive rewrite rules, and puts the management of the old-to-new mappings into, why by jove, a database why not! :)

Hope this helps spawn new ideas...